# Use SegmentControl to alternate display text and image

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I want use the SegmentControl so that when

selectedSegmentIndex == 0

a text is displayed in the scene

but when

selectedSegmentIndex == 1

an image is displayed (with UIImageView) in the same spot as the text (the text disappears)

Should I just overlay the UIlabel with the UIImageView, then set their contents with different SegmentIndex?

It would look pretty ugly and I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

By looking in the document of Apple, I think that it's possible natively:

"A segment may either have a text title or an image, **but not both**"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```